# Error installing Dlib library for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmake, face-detection, dlib

While trying to install Dlib library for Python, using this tutorial http://dlib.net/compile.html.

This tutorial says to do this -

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

I have created a build and when I'm giving the command **cmake ..**

It shows me this error -

```
 CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Python27/dlib-19.4.0/python_examples" 
 does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

Comment: You are trying to compile the python examples, which do not need to be compiled. Only the C++ example can be compiled. Just use the *.py files directly

Answer (score 1):

These examples do not need to be compiled, only the C++ one have to.

You will however have to compile the dlib python interface, you will find information about this right underneath the C++ section, on this page : http://dlib.net/compile.html

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to install dlib:
just execute below command line.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libboost-python-dev
pip install dlib
```